# Python indirect indexing

Tags: python, matrix-indexing

This might be a super easy question if you know how to do it, but I just can't figure out the syntax:

I have an array of 5x10 zeros: `y1 = np.zeros((5,10))` and an array 5x1 of index: `index=np.array([2,3,2,5,6])`. For each row of `y1`, I would like to set 1 at the column given by the index. The result would look like

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Anyone can help please :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do multi-dimensional array indexing with `array[index_1, index_2]`. For your problem:

```
y1[range(y1.shape[0]), index] = 1
```

range(y1.shape[0]) generates the array `[0,1,...,n-1]`, where `n` is the number of rows in y1. This array is your row index, and index is your column index.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an enumerate()

```
import numpy as np

y1 = np.zeros((5,10))
index=np.array([2,3,2,5,6])


for i,item in enumerate(y1):
    item[index[i]] = 1

print(y1)
# [[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 # [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 # [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 # [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 # [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Sorry I should mention that I don't want to use a for loop because it will be very slow. I am looking a vectorised solution